Is it possible to compress xz multi-block stream with different filter chain for each block?
I use the library liblzma from XZUtils.
I can multithreaded compress a multiblock / multistream xz with:
lzma_stream_compress_mt(..)
lzma_code(..)
lzma_end(..)

Lets say that I concatenate (while uncompressed) a README.TXT file and a PROGRAM.EXE file to a stream, each file a block.
I want for first block only lzma filter and for second block bjc_x86 filter and then lzma filter.
But filter chain defined in lzma_stream_compress_mt(..) and block change with action parameter LZMA_FULL_BARRIER in lzma_code(..).
Is there any trick to change filters by block in liblzma?
I see much of functionality in the API but examples are very basic.
